# The Keyboard Shift Cipher

Tags: code-golf, keyboard, cipher

Given the following input:

- An integer `n` where `n > 0`.
- A string `s` where `s` is not empty and `s~=[0-9A-Z]+` (alpha-numeric capitals only).

Using a standard, simplified QWERTY keyboard (as shown below):

```
1234567890
QWERTYUIOP
ASDFGHJKL
ZXCVBNM
```

Perform the following operation:

- Find the original row that each character is in on the keyboard.
- Replace the letter with the correct shifted equivalent for `n` based on its original position + n.

  - E.G. `s="AB"` and `n=2`: `A` would become `D` and `B` would become `M`.
- If `keyboard_row[position + n] > keyboard_row.length`, wrap back to the start.

  - E.G. `s="0P"` and `n=2`: `0` would become `2` and `P` would become `W`.

## Examples:

```
f("0PLM",1)    = 1QAZ
f("ZXCVB",2)   = CVBNM
f("HELLO",3)   = LYDDW
f("0PLM",11)   = 1QSV
f("0PLM",2130) = 0PHX
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

---

*This is slightly more difficult than it seems at first glance.*

Comment: Are we allowed to take the input as character-array instead of string? Currently assumed we, but forgot to ask..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen *shrug* sure, it's not too outlandish. Unless it saves you a byte to break a tie I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ØQØDṭ,ṙ€¥⁸F€y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMDDM1we7lyr83DnzEdNaw4tfdS4ww3IqPx/eLmRfuT//4Y6CkoGAT6@SjoKRkBmVIRzmBOQbQxke7j6@PgD2YbIagyNDWA8AA)

#### How it works

```
ØQØDṭ,ṙ€¥⁸F€y  Main link. Left argument: n (integer). Right argument: s (string)

ØQ             Qwerty; set the return value to
               ["QWERTYUIOP", "ASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM"].
  ØD           Digits; yield "0123456789".
    ṭ          Tack, yielding ["QWERTYUIOP", "ASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM", "0123456789"].
        ¥⁸     Call the two links to the left as a dyadic chain, with right
               argument n.
      ṙ€       Rotate each string in the array n units to the left.
     ,         Yield the pair of the unmodified and the rotated string array.
          F€   Flatten each, mapping, e.g., ["QWERTYUIOP", ..., "0123456789"] to
               "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789".
            y  Translate s according to the mapping we've built.
```

Comment: Jelly has keyboard-layout built-ins eh?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No, only QWERTY right now :-P

Comment: 13 bytes? Which character set is that supposed to be? In UTF-8 it's 26 bytes!

Comment: @Cephalopod Jelly uses the [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: I'm not going to complain about regex anymore

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 110 bytes

```python
lambda s,n,y='1234567890'*99+'QWERTYUIOP'*99+'ASDFGHJKL'*99+'ZXCVBNM'*99:''.join(y[y.find(c)+n%630]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Lb8IwEITv/Apfqk3KFuXRAkFyJWgoaTHl1fIKOVAgahB1UGwO@fVpHPfAbecbze7sJZc/KXeKmG6L8@73@7AjAjnmFGzHfXxqttqeBfeeV4fpsj/7XH@9jSdad@f@6yB4HzItN6uXRe9jpEQHoHFKE27kYd6IE34w9mad3zVdK4rTjOxJwokwC3kUUtCwFoI1YSNAG8GedjcQYYmqdYAOgl5bwaDP2BjQRWBr319q@B@u0vPFLXNs18JyDlaKRjV1XD2XHcX1LFWLqkLnkiVcktgoPZNS7SIJSxkhPDwDaqv4Aw)

This uses a big enough string (99 copies of each row) and the LCM between the rows lengths (630) to find the correct substitution avoiding individual correction between each row.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>159</s> 158 bytes

```java
n->s->{for(int i=s.length,j;i-->0;)for(String x:"1234567890;QWERTYUIOP;ASDFGHJKL;ZXCVBNM".split(";"))if((j=x.indexOf(s[i])+n)>=n)s[i]=x.charAt(j%x.length());}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* modifying the input-array instead of printing directly.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVHbTsJAEH33KzZNTHZjuwHxvtIEEa9FULwTHtaywGKZNt2tlhi@vW5xE8WQzMPkzJmZM2em/IN7cSJgOnwvwogrhdpcwtcGQkpzLUM0NQyaaRnRUQahljHQM5scX4IWY5G660jNGFQ2E@lxOOFpf@D7KER1VIDnK8//GsUplqCRrCsaCRjricuZ9Dy/wkhZ6@lUwhjlR051u7azu7d/cFhht0@tu/uXh8tOlzV6p2fnF1fXAXt9bj6e3LQdqpJIauwwhxA5wpjXcyphKPLOCKu@HJAtIH4dSJmbUqmqoTHfzO1@TAhbFMwcbiLJ3iJzu7XgI5ZDNDO2WFn9ASelQwhpoTTedp3GiUPYClLpriDVEgna/1lL8StgzXUuWkHQWe1e216tVf7Ci43fpy0VL1mlyeAi66eyun9@grj5iKI6bpZmpCmfY7sgpDxJojkGQnkYisQYZSu9udJiRuNM08SM1BFgEJ92vmFZKYviGw)

```java
n->s->{  // Method with integer and character-array parameters, and no return-type
  for(int i=s.length,j;i-->0;)
         //  Loop over the input character-array with index
    for(String x:"1234567890;QWERTYUIOP;ASDFGHJKL;ZXCVBNM".split(";"))
         //   Inner loop over the qwerty-lines
      if((j=x.indexOf(s[i])+n)>=n)
         //    If the current qwerty-line contains the character
         //     Set `j` to the index of this character on that line + input `n`
        s[i]=x.charAt(j%x.length());}
         //     Replace the character at index `i`
         //     with the new character (at index `j` modulo length_of_qwerty_line)
```

Comment: [158 bytes](http://bit.ly/2FQBj2e), at the cost of input-outputting the `char[]`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 49 bytes

```
"$&"+T`9o`dQW\ERTYUI\OPQASDFG\HJK\LAZXC\VBNMZ
0A`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0lFTUk7JMEyPyElMDzGNSgkMtQzxj8g0DHYxc09xsPLO8bHMSrCOSbMyc83isvAMeH/f2MuD1cfH38A) Takes input `n` and `s` on separate lines. Explanation:

```
"$&"+
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
T`9o`dQW\ERTYUI\OPQASDFG\HJK\LAZXC\VBNMZ
```

Shift all the characters one key to the right.

```
0A`
```

Delete `n`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>101</s> 99 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(s)(n)`. Works with arrays of characters.

```js
s=>n=>s.map(c=>(S='1QAZ2WSX3EDC4RFV5TGB6YHN7UJM8IK_9OL_0P')[(p=S.search(c)+n*4)%(-~'9986'[p%4]*4)])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>n=>s.map(c=>(S='1QAZ2WSX3EDC4RFV5TGB6YHN7UJM8IK_9OL_0P')[(p=S.search(c)+n*4)%(-~'9986'[p%4]*4)])

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([..."0PLM"])(1)))    // 1QAZ
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([..."ZXCVB"])(2)))   // CVBNM
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([..."HELLO"])(3)))   // LYDDW
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([..."0PLM"])(11)))   // 1QSV
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([..."0PLM"])(2130))) // 0PHX
```

#### How?

We look for the position **p** of each character of the input within a string **S** where the keyboard rows are interleaved: the first 4 characters are **'1QAZ'** (first column of the keyboard), the next 4 characters are **'2WSX'** (second column of the keyboard) and so on. Unused positions are padded with underscores and the last ones are simply discarded.

```
col # | 0    | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9
------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---
row # | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 0123 | 01
------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---
char. | 1QAZ | 2WSX | 3EDC | 4RFV | 5TGB | 6YHN | 7UJM | 8IK_ | 9OL_ | 0P
```

This allows us to easily identify the row with **p mod 4** and eliminates the need for explicit separators between the rows.

We advance by **4n** positions, apply the correct modulo for this row (40, 40, 36 and 28 respectively) and pick the replacement character found at this new position in **S**.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ØQØDṭẋ€‘}Ẏ©iÐ€⁸+ị®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMDDM1we7lz7cFf3o6Y1jxpm1D7c1XdoZebhCSBu4w7th7u7D637//@/kkGAj6/Sf0MA)

Answer (score 3):

## C,  <s>152</s>  149 bytes

*Thanks to @gastropner for saving three bytes!*

```c
j,l;f(S,n){for(char*s=S,*k;*s;++s)for(k="1234567890\0QWERTYUIOP\0ASDFGHJKL\0ZXCVBNM\0";l=strlen(k);k+=l+1)for(j=l;j--;)k[j]-*s||putchar(k[(j+n)%l]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1dT8IwGIXv@RWkiUnftUvaTUTzphd@oChD0PnNuCCLU9pazDqvgN8@B5E7PJfPk3NOHn7keV1rbrGgKXewLBYlzT9nZeBVygODgUfGPGywUURG8WHnqHt8IjJx99y7f3h9vB6NM3GaXlxe9W8GSSbeXs6fzm6HmSBola9K@@6oATRMWSa3O1pZ1GGIYCZ6GgZ@tfr@qTaf1EyoZg4O7BRwXc9d1f6azR2F1rLVblJQIsbJkHAJ2FQ8JQRwZ7a/hEd7VL@XJCPC4z3qb0/@qyIZi4at618)

**Unrolled:**

```c
j,l;
f(S,n)
{
    for (char*s=S, *k; *s; ++s)
        for (k="1234567890\0QWERTYUIOP\0ASDFGHJKL\0ZXCVBNM\0"; l=strlen(k); k+=l+1)
            for (j=l; j--;)
                k[j]-*s || putchar(k[(j+n)%l]);
}
```

Comment: Either I'm hallucinating, or the inner loop can be changed to `for(j=l;j--;)` but I don't know why without any other changed. Still, should get you to 149.

Comment: @gastropner Ah, yes, the search order doesn't matter, so it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 152 bytes

```
f: func[s n][foreach c s[foreach[t l]["1234567890"10"QWERTYUIOP"10"ASDFGHJKL"9"ZXCVBNM"7][if p: find t c[if(i:(index? p)+ n // l)= 0[i: l]prin t/(i)]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1NT8JAGITv/IrJe2rjobutCm1CDGoFtQjyIehmD6bdDZs0a1Nq4N@XxcCJOKd58iQztSramSogZKsT6F@biy2sFPqnVt/5Bjm25y4alFIQD6Prm9tuL2bEGb2v0tnic/k8mR5pMH98Go5eXjOK6Wv98HH/NqauFEajcuPGFmiQO/RM4jlS@ztU/hUsggCl3wcTJnEnVW0smsAzvnRpNYhNszGBd46mgVW70ljVceLvhRBemlGaZRNCBFy60xz/z4Q8Yu0B)

Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s n][1
    foreach c s [
        foreach [t l] ["1234567890"10"QWERTYUIOP"10"ASDFGHJKL"9"ZXCVBNM"7][
            p: find t c
            if p [ 
                i: (index? p) + n // l
                if i = 0 [i: l]
                prin t/(i) ]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 99 bytes

```hs
f(s,n)=[dropWhile(/=c)(cycle r)!!n|c<-s,r<-words"1234567890 QWERTYUIOP ASDFGHJKL ZXCVBNM",elem c r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnbCoIwAADQX5k@bTDJaVfQh@43K7taiQ8yJ0pzyhZE4L@vzuspUvVinGudQ4UF8uNM1k1UlJzBjk8RpF/KGZDIMERLPUth6VmfWmbKJI7b7fUHw5ENjtH8dHlc14cQjM@zxXK12QbgeZ/eJvudiRlnFaBAJrpKS@E3shTvOIemHQb/FagVnhUTTAh2iGsnif4B)

Comment: You can use `s#n= ...` instead of `f(s,n)= ...` which is only an example notation used for the examples.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 94 + 1 (`-p`) = 95 bytes

```perl
$s=<>;for$i(1234567890,QWERTYUIOP,ASDFGHJKL,ZXCVBNM){eval"y/$i/".(substr$i,$s%length$i)."$i/"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@l2NbGzjotv0glU8PQyNjE1MzcwtJAJzDcNSgkMtTTP0DHMdjFzd3Dy9tHJyrCOczJz1ezOrUsMUepUl8lU19JT6O4NKm4BKhdR6VYNSc1L70kQyVTU08JJFn7/79BgI8vl5GhscG//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYG/3ULAA)

Comment: Damn, I didn't see your answer. They're basically the same, feel free to use my optimisations and I'll remove my answer. Let me know, if not, I'll just remove this comment :)

Comment: @DomHastings They are different enough. Please keep both. I like to see variations in approach. I learn from all of them...

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 20 bytes

Running out the door to dinner so more golfing and an explanation to follow.

```
;£=D·i9òs)æøX)gV+UbX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O6M9RLdpOfJzKeb4WClnVitVYlg=&input=IjBQTE0iLDIxMzA=)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>59</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

Includes `+` for `-p`

Give input on STDIN as 2 lines, first the string, then the repeat

```
(echo 0PLM; echo 2130) | perl -pe '$a="OPQWERTYUILASDF-MZXCVBNM0-90";eval"y/HI$a/J$a/;"x<>'
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe you got 29 bytes off mine! I was pretty happy with it originally...

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 85 bytes

**84 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
eval join"",map"y/$_/@{[/./&&$'.$&]}/;",(1234567890,QWERTYUIOP,ASDFGHJKL,ZXCVBNM)x<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHISs/M09JSSc3sUCpUl8lXt@hOlpfT19NTUVdT0UttlbfWklHw9DI2MTUzNzC0kAnMNw1KCQy1NM/QMcx2MXN3cPL20cnKsI5zMnPV7PCxu7/f4MAH18uQy6wGJcRl4erj48/lzEXRNgQQhsZGhtw/csvKMnMzyv@r1sAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>144</s> 119 bytes

```
import StdEnv
```

```
\n s=[l.[(i+n)rem(size l)]\\c<-s,l<-["1234567890","QWERTYUIOP","ASDFGHJKL","ZXCVBNM"],i<-[0..]&j<-:l|j==c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r@x/cEliUQmXskKagq1CTJ5CsW10jl60RqZ2nmZRaq5GcWZVqkKOZmxMTLKNbrFOjo1utJKhkbGJqZm5haWBko5SYLhrUEhkqKd/AJDjGOzi5u7h5e0DZEdFOIc5@fkqxepkAjUZ6OnFqmXZ6Frl1GTZ2ibHctkCLTRWiFb3cPXx8VeP/f8vOS0nMb34v66nz3@XyrzE3MxkCAfoTJ/MJAA)

Lambda function with the signature `Int ![Char] -> [Char]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 101 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{n.times{s.tr! '1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM','2345678901WERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLAXCVBNMZ'};s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165YJ686T68kMze1uLpYr6RIUUHd0MjYxNTM3MLSIDDcNSgkMtTTP8Ax2MXN3cPL2ycqwjnMyc9XXUcdrsoQrioQpsoRoipKvda6uPZ/NJeCQrSSQYCPr5KOYawOmAc2R0nHCMr1cPXx8VfSMYZyoWoNUbhGhsYGsVyxeqmJyRkKKfkKNcU6CkU1QAUFpSXFCml6yYk5OQogMa7UvJT/AA)

I'm honestly a little disappointed that I couldn't do better with 'cleverer' methods. The closest I got was along the lines of

```ruby
a=%w{1234567890 QWERTYUIOP ASDFGHJKL ZXCVBNM}
b=a.map{|r|r[1..-1]<<r[0]}*''
a*=''
n.times{s.tr! a,b}
```

for a net gain of 7 characters.